# Data throughput/latency and poe performance in TPLINK TL-SG2424P 24 ports POE Managed Switch

Tags: performance, switch, power-over-ethernet

I recently bought a TPLINK TL-SG2424P 24 ports POE Managed Switch.

At the moment I'm going to use it with only a handful of access points, no more than 4 or 5, at least until the end of the year when we will change building and we will need quite a lot more.

The question is : there is a better way to choose which 4 of the 24 ports to use in the switch, either with respect to data throughput/latency or with poe performance?

From what I remember from college, I'm guessing that by using ports as separated as possible I should achieve higher latencies but better throughput but what about POE?

There's a way to reduce consumption / heating? Should I be worried about it when I will be using 20 or 22 PDs with it?

Thanks for any help.